# Disable scrolling phone:webbrowser windows phone 8 / 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to disable the scroll functionality in the phone:webbrowser in my windows phone 8 application. The reason i wan't to do this is that I want to place a stackpanel with items underneath the webview, but still show the whole webpage.

To accomplish this I get the total height of the webpage and set the height of the webbrowser to the webpage height. This will be done through adding javascript to the webbrowser. The webview will now have the total webpage and the items underneath it and both of those items are in a **ScrollViewer** so you can scroll through the page.

The only problem i have right now is that you can scroll the webbrowser so you cant scroll the scrollviewer. anyone got an idea how to fix this?

```
<ScrollViewer
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="0,0,0,0">

    <StackPanel  
        x:Name="ContentPanel"
        Margin="0,0,0,0">

        <phone:WebBrowser
            x:Name="webView" 
            Navigating="WebBrowserNavigating"
            LoadCompleted="WebBrowserLoadCompleted"
            ScriptNotify="browser_ScriptNotify"
            IsScriptEnabled="True"/>

            <StackPanel
                x:Name="CouponHolder"
                Margin="0,5,0,0">

            </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I also looked at other questions, but they didnt work out for me:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/718671/Disable-WebView-scrolling-in-Windows-Store-Apps

And I see allot of people give awnsers like VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" but this doesnt work, like the suggests it will only hide the visibility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can disable all manipulation with WebBrowser control by setting IsHitTestVisible="false". The disadvantage is that you can't press Links, Navigate and so on.

If you want just to disable scrolling than take a look at this blog post:http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/11/17/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control.html

You can Find that the VisualTree of WebBrowser control looks like:

```
    \-WebBrowser
     \-Border
      \-Border
       \WebBrowserInteropCanvas (New in Windows Phone 8, missing in WP7)
        \-PanZoomContainer
         \-Grid
          \-Border (you need access this one)
           \-ContentPresenter
            \-TileHost
```

You can get the last Border in VisualTree, and subscribe to ManipulationDelta, ManipulationStarted and ManipulationCompletedEvents. And set e.Handled = true; In event handlers. Be careful with that. For example where is no equialent for this code in Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 (Runtime).

This hack will cancel scrolling of webbrowser while user can interract with entire web page, but you won't be able to suppress manipulation to put webbrowser in scrollviewer.

In general I don't think that you could achive ideal user experience if you put WebBrowser inside ScrollViewer

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. After your comment I concluded to change the views. Because this wouldnt work on WP8.1 right?

Comment: Yes, I think it wouldn't work for WP8.1 Runtime, but it might still  work for WP 8.1 Silverlight.

Comment: The app I am working on is the second version so I can't change it to silverlight. thnx for the help

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching this project finally solved all our webview problems in Windows Phone 8.1 (bounce, touch, auto height etc.):
https://github.com/romshiri/sizeable-webview